# Computing the area of discrete points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, area, points

I have a set of discrete points in 2D, which need to compute the internal area, or simply length and height, does not matter obviously. But the point for this question is; not necessarily we have sharp edges which shape the internal surface. I tried the commands `boundary` and `inpolygon`, but seems are not the right ones for this problem. How about edges which we do not have straight edges, like arcs or semi circles.

**https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-DuVkE6qbU3ZnJsbWdQNjVmVkk/view?usp=sharing**

The files provided inside link:

- File 1 consist of XYZ coordinates plus intensity (comes by laser scanned data) values
- File 2 consist of XYZ coordinates plus intensity, while all Z and intensity values are fixed through the file.
- Figures 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4 represent the data in 3D with associated intensity values. Different intensity values displays different materials. The white arrows showcase the depth of different parts of segment.
- Figure 2-1, 2-2 represent the data in 2D with only one intensity values. Actually, in this step, the 3D data was projected into 2D and all intensity values changed to only one value, additionally, the internal part of window was removed. The area of internal part is of the interest to be computed.

It's been a challenge for me! Could anyone advise please?

Comment: A point is, by definition, something with zero area. Unless you mean something else and you are not showing it. Is this image processing? can we see the images? What have you tried?

Comment: Could you advise how I can upload screen shot of points or the ascii file? Actually it is not an image structure, i.e. not a pixel format. it is just discrete points, means x,y coordinates, but obviously not connected.

Comment: In the question editor you have a button to upload images. Or you can upload the image in an external site and provide a link (there's a button for links also)

Comment: @Sophia Discrete poitns have no area

Comment: If you tried `inpolygon` it makes me think that your set of points are the vertex points of a polygon and you want to calculate the area of that polygon. Take in account that the order of the points matter, since you can have different valid ordered points that form different polygons with different areas (a set of ordered points is valid if segments do not cross).

Comment: Did my solution work on your case?

Comment: Dear Ander Biguri, Sembei Norimaki, RCaetano,
Could you please have a look at the data I provided. I shared them on google drive.
Cheers, Sophia

Comment: I marked the area of interest by a white rectangle in Figure 1-2 (representation of 3D plus intensity) and also in Figure 2-2 (projected 3D to 2D plus similar intensity for whole points)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `imclose`, `imdilate` or `imerode` functions in order to obtain an unique "object" and then you can compute the area by summing all the values diferent from 0 or 255, according to your implementation. I am assuming that the image is black and white, otherwise convert it first.
Matlab documentation:

- imclose: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html
- im2bw: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html

Comment: Dear RCaetano, I provided a link to the data, also more explanation to the problem.

Comment: It is not an image problem. In ascii file, there are xyz coordinates plus intensity value. Intensity is a property of the point which related to some parameters such as the material.

Answer (score 0):

If your points are the vertex coordinates of a polygon, then you can use `polyarea` to return the area of that polygon.

Ex:

```
Area = polyarea(pointsX, pointsY)
```

Take in account that the order of the points matter, and they must form a valid polygon (segments must not cross)

Comment: Dear Sembei, I provided a link to the data, also more explanation to the problem.

Comment: As it can be seen in ascii file, there is no particular order between points recorded to build the ascii file. They have been recorded randomly.

Comment: You can put a threshold in the Z coordinate (depth). so you will end with a binary image with the objects at a certain depth. Once you have the binary image you will probably need some morphology to clean it, and then you can use `bwarea`. Take a look at http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwarea.html

Comment: This problem understudy does not have an image characteristics.